# Date not inserting in mysql_query insert

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert-update

I am trying to insert a row into database. All entries insert correctly, however the date is inserted as:

```
0000-00-00
```

I have tried formatting the date manually:

```
        $updated = $a["updated"][0];

        $updated = explode(" ", $updated);
        $updated[1] = explode("/", $updated[1]);

        $y = date('Y');
        $m = $updated[1][1];
        $d = $updated[1][0];

        $updated = $y . '-' . $m . '-' . $d;

        $updated = strtotime( $updated );
        echo '<pre>'. $updated .'</pre>';
        $upd = date('Y-m-d', $updated);

        $a["updated"][0] = $updated;            
        echo '<pre>'. $upd .'</pre>';
```

This is the output of the var_dump($a):

```
1342134000

2012-07-13

array(3) {
  ["metal"]=>
  string(6) "Silver"
  ["am"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "2748.00"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "1779.220"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "2253.200"
  }
  ["updated"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(1342134000)
  }
}
```

I have also tried using mysql_date_format but the row is not inserted at all:

```
$updated = mysql_date_format($updated);
```

This is my insert query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO LondonFixes VALUES(null,'" . $a["metal"] . "','AM'," . $a["am"][1] . "," . $a["am"][0] . "," . $a["am"][2] . "," . $a["updated"][0] . ", null)");
```

This is my table structure

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `LondonFixes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Metal` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `AmPm` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `GBP` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL,
  `USD` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL,
  `EUR` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL,
  `Updated` date NOT NULL,
  `TimeStamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Entry` (`Metal`,`AmPm`,`Updated`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=229 ;
```

There is probably a very simple solution to this, but go easy on me please!

Comment: Have you tried hard-wiring a date in to your statement, just to make sure that the format your query is using is the same one that the database is expecting?

Comment: The value of `$a["updated][0]` appears to an integer unix timestamp value, rather than a formatted date string. To pass in the integer value, wrap it in a `FROM_UNIXTIME` in your SQL statement, -or- pass in the the formatted date string.  (See my answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Month and day require leading zero.

Use:

```
$upd = date('Y-m-d', $updated);
```

Also be sure that your date is enclosing by quotations like string.

```
,'" . $a["updated"][0] . "'
```

In your code you do not have quotations for the date.

Comment: The `n` token is month *without* leading zeros - did you mean `Y-m-d` ?

Comment: Check my last comment I added missing quotation that you have. Dates require a quotation like string.

Comment: Actually, the month and day do not require leading zeros. MySQL handles date strings that are missing the leading zeros just fine. I think it's good practice to use the leading zeros. I prefer strings that are canonical (that is, sort by date value correctly when sorted as strings.) However, the MySQL INSERT statement doesn't require a two position month or two position day.

Comment: Thank You @spencer7593 may be the leading zero could be more a good practice, rather than a current Mysql requirement, I just remember that the 0000-00-00 dates are commonly because two issues, one is the missing leading zero(old versions) and the other one is missing quotations.

Comment: @Daniel, another way to get the "zero date" is to assign a unix timestamp integer, which is what the OP's code is doing...  That's what the code he posted does anyway; it's not putting a formatted string in the SQL text.